# fltk widget order, button is hide under another widget

Tags: fltk

I am using fltk 1.3.2.

I have two widgets, one of them is `Fl_Multiline_Output` and other one is `Fl_Button`.

The button is a place on the the `multiline_output`. 
When I click `multiline_output`, the button is disappeared. 
I need to use always on top like speciality for my button. 
It mustn't be hide.

Does anyone know fltk support this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have changed `Fl_Multiline_Output` to `Fl_Text_Display`, I put the text and deactivated it. Now, when I click `Fl_Text_Display` nothing is happen.

I changed to `Fl_Text_Display` because if I deactivate the `Fl_Multiline_Output` object, text color is changed. I chose `Fl_Text_Display` there is no problem with text color.